# Max heapify infinite loop when used on array but not vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a max-heapify function that I used for a vector to work with sorting an array of ints, however, when I run it, I am running into an infinite loop.

I believe the logic of my algorithm seems to be right, however, my siftdown function doesnt seem to function properly.

```
void Sort::heapify(int *array, int size){
    for(int i = (size-2)/2;i >= 0;i--){
        siftdown(array, i, size);
    }
}
void Sort::siftdown(int *array, int i, int size){
    if(i >= size || i < 0){
        cout << "i is >= size of playerArray or i < 0. i: " << i << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<< "passed something" <<endl;
    while(!isLeaf(array, i, size)){
        cout<<"!isLeaf"<<endl;
        int max = getLeft(i);
        if(max + 1 < size && array[max] < array[max +1]){
            max++;
            cout << "added to max.";
        }
        if (array[i] > array[max]){
            cout<< "array[i] is > than array[max]"<<endl;
            return;
        }

        swap(i, max);
        i = max;
    }
    cout<<"isLeaf"<<endl;
}
int Sort::getLeft(int index){
//gets the left most leaf
    int left = 2*index+1;
    return left;
}
bool Sort::isLeaf(int *array, int index, int size){
    //A node is a leaf node if both left and right child nodes of it are NULL.
    int left = 2*index+1;
    int right = left+1;
    if(left>size  && right>size) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "_I believe the logic of my algorithm seems to be right_" Did you debug your code statement by statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write (in the body of `while` in `Sort::siftdown()`)

```
    swap(i, max);
    i = max;
```

you're ending with `i` and `max` with the old value of `i`; so you repeat

```
while(!isLeaf(array, i, size))
```

with the same values.

Loop!

Comment: Oh!! My problem was that I was trying to swap the values in array[i] and array[max], but ended up just swapping i and max.

Thank you!